# how to convert a np array of lists to a np array

Tags: python, numpy

**latest updated:**

```
>>> a = np.array(["0,1", "2,3", "4,5"])
>>> a
array(['0,1', '2,3', '4,5'], dtype='|S3')
>>> b = np.core.defchararray.split(a, sep=',')
>>> b
array([list(['0', '1']), list(['2', '3']), list(['4', '5'])], dtype=object)
>>> c = np.array(b).astype(float)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

**old:**

I have a np array like this:

```
array([[list(['3', '6']), list(['2', '1'])],
       [list(['0', '7']), list(['1', ' 9'])]], dtype=object)
```

I want to convert it to a np array of string like this:

```
array([[['3', '6'], ['2', '1']],
       [['0', '7'], ['1', ' 9']]], dtype=object)
```

so that I can use astype("float32") to directly convert it to a float array.

any idea?

**old update:**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uoIp7.png)

thx for your suggestions but I cannot find the difference.

Comment: Did you try `np.array(array)`

Comment: Or even `np.array(arr).astype(float)`.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ yep. however, it keeps the array in its original shape and types.

Comment: @jpp thx for ur reply. np.array() does NOT work in this scenario.

Comment: Then you quite certainly have ragged arrays with unequal sizes.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I think I have not described clearly. I am not converting a list or array. I am converting a np array. You can see the image I updated. It will be more clear.

Comment: @WongJones, please do not use images. If you need to explain problem more clearly, feel free to update your question. Improving your question is *encouraged*.

Comment: @WongJones Looks like you still don't get it. Please do this: `np.unique(list(map(len, array)))` and tell me what it prints out

Comment: Try `np.array(arr.tolist())`.  Or `np.stack(arr.ravel()).reshape(2,2,2)`

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ   sorry for bad description which makes it confusing. I updated it again. thx for your reply.

Comment: @WongJones, see updated answer. The solution hasn't changed.

Comment: @hpaulj yes, it works. just np.array(b.tolist()).astype(float). I got a [3, 2] 2-d array of float type. thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was wondering how you got the array of lists.  That usually takes some trickery.

```
In [2]: >>> a = np.array(["0,1", "2,3", "4,5"])
   ...: >>> b = np.core.defchararray.split(a, sep=',')
   ...: 
In [4]: b
Out[4]: array([list(['0', '1']), list(['2', '3']), list(['4', '5'])], dtype=object)
```

Simply calling array again doesn't change things:

```
In [5]: np.array(b)
Out[5]: array([list(['0', '1']), list(['2', '3']), list(['4', '5'])], dtype=object)
```

`stack` works - it views `b` as a list of elements, in this case lists, and joins them on a new axis

```
In [6]: np.stack(b)
Out[6]: 
array([['0', '1'],
       ['2', '3'],
       ['4', '5']], dtype='<U1')
In [7]: np.stack(b).astype(float)
Out[7]: 
array([[0., 1.],
       [2., 3.],
       [4., 5.]])
```

But your 'old' case was a 2d array of lists.  This stack trick does not work, at least not directly.

```
In [8]: a = np.array(["0,1", "2,3", "4,5","6,7"]).reshape(2,2)
In [9]: b = np.core.defchararray.split(a, sep=',')
In [11]: np.stack(b)
Out[11]: 
array([[list(['0', '1']), list(['2', '3'])],
       [list(['4', '5']), list(['6', '7'])]], dtype=object)

In [12]: np.stack(b.ravel())
Out[12]: 
array([['0', '1'],
       ['2', '3'],
       ['4', '5'],
       ['6', '7']], dtype='<U1')
```

or

```
In [13]: np.array(b.tolist())
Out[13]: 
array([[['0', '1'],
        ['2', '3']],

       [['4', '5'],
        ['6', '7']]], dtype='<U1')
```

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion in comments works fine for me.

```
arr = np.array([list(['0', '1']), list(['2', '3']), list(['4', '5'])], dtype=object)

res = np.array(arr).astype(float)

print(res, res.dtype, res.shape)

# [[ 0.  1.]
#  [ 2.  3.]
#  [ 4.  5.]] float64 (3, 2)
```

Comment: hi jpp, could you take a look at my updated image? I cannot work in the same way as your example.

Comment: hi jpp, you are not convert an 2-d np array of list into a 3-d np array, the argument in np.array() is an array of array of list....they are different.

Comment: Still don't understand. Result *is* a 3d array, see update with `shape` output.

Comment: I am almost certain OP's data does not even remotely resemble this perfect MCVE. They have an array of ragged lists, but for some reason they seem to be dodging... ah :|

Comment: @jpp hi, in my question, the original array is a 2-D np array whose elements are of list type. In your answer, the arr is a 3-D np array.

Comment: So can you fix your question? The first sentence says that you start with a 3d `numpy` array.

Comment: @jpp I updated accordingly. sorry for making you confused.

Comment: Creating a 2d array from a triple nest lists is a bit tricky. Your `arr` is not the same as the OP's.

Comment: @hpaulj, interesting - it seems to work in my example, no? [OP updated his problem]