# remove list from numpy

Tags: numpy, jupyter-notebook

I have a numpy array called genes and for some reason it has the identifier list. How would I proceed to remove the list part and simply keep the elements. Here is the output of genes:

```
array([[list(['0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0'])], 
       [list(['0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0'])]
      ], dtype=object)
```

The desired output would simply be the same without the list. The rest would remain the same:

```
array([['0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0'], 
       ['0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0']
      ], dtype=object)
```

Here is how I got the numpy array:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.set_printoptions(threshold=np.nan)


url = "https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/molecular-biology/splice-junction-gene-sequences/splice.data"
file = pd.read_csv(url, delimiter=',', header=None,dtype='str')

X = file[2]
y = file[0]

df = np.array(X)
newDf = df.astype(str)

newerDf = newDf.reshape(( newDf.size, 1))

newestDf = np.char.strip(newerDf)

genes = np.char.array(newestDf)

genes = np.char.replace(genes, 'A', '0001')
genes = np.char.replace(genes, 'C', '0010')
genes = np.char.replace(genes, 'G', '0100')
genes = np.char.replace(genes, 'T', '1000')
genes = np.char.join(',', genes)
genes = np.char.split(genes, ',')

genes
```

Comment: Where did the data come from?

Comment: Just run the command `np.char.array(genes)`. You'll end up with an additional dimension on the second to last axis, after which you can just `reshape` to remove it.

Comment: @droooze it gives me the following error: setting an array element with a sequence

Comment: @StephenRauch I update the initial post to show how I obtained and shaped the data

Comment: [I can't reproduce your error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LxIkz.png).

Comment: @droooze I posted my code, try running it and adding the     np.char.array(genes) line

Comment: Ah, your gene sequences are of different lengths. You should initialise the array to the longest length sequence first before attempting to do your whole problem this way.

Comment: The sequence is of same length, I remove the spaces and only keep the gene sequences, which are of length 60. You can find the data here https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/molecular-biology/splice-junction-gene-sequences/splice.data. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I've seen something like this recently.  Usually it's not easy to create an object dtype array with list elements of matching size.  For example a copy-n-paste of your first line produces a `(2, 1, 240)` shape array.  But that case, like yours, used a `char.split`.

[how to convert a np array of lists to a np array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49364432/how-to-convert-a-np-array-of-lists-to-a-np-array)

A simpler case:

```
In [138]: x = np.array(['abc def','hij klm'])
In [139]: np.char.split(x)
Out[139]: array([list(['abc', 'def']), list(['hij', 'klm'])], dtype=object)
In [140]: x = np.array(['abc def','hij klm'])
In [141]: y = np.char.split(x)
In [142]: y
Out[142]: array([list(['abc', 'def']), list(['hij', 'klm'])], dtype=object)
In [143]: np.stack(y)
Out[143]: 
array([['abc', 'def'],
       ['hij', 'klm']], dtype='<U3')
In [144]: _.shape
Out[144]: (2, 2)
```

---

Looking at your display more carefully I see another dimension, more like this:

```
In [145]: x = np.array([['abc def'],['hij klm']])
In [146]: x.shape
Out[146]: (2, 1)
In [147]: x
Out[147]: 
array([['abc def'],
       ['hij klm']], dtype='<U7')
In [148]: y = np.char.split(x)
In [149]: y
Out[149]: 
array([[list(['abc', 'def'])],
       [list(['hij', 'klm'])]], dtype=object)
In [150]: y.shape
Out[150]: (2, 1)
```

`np.stack` doesn't help, but if we first flatten `y` it works:

```
In [152]: np.stack(y.ravel())
Out[152]: 
array([['abc', 'def'],
       ['hij', 'klm']], dtype='<U3')
```

Comment: Trying np.stack(genes.ravel()) with my code, it gives me the following error: all input arrays must have the same shape. I am double checking the dataset, but they all seem to be of length 60

Answer (score 0):

You can go through `tolist`:

```
>>> A
array([[list(['0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0'])],
       [list(['0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0'])]],
      dtype=object)
>>> 
>>> np.array(A.tolist(), object)
array([[['0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1',
         '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0',
         '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1',
         '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1',
         '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0',
         '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0',
         '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0',
         '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0',
         '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0',
         '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0',
         '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0',
         '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0',
         '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0',
         '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0',
         '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0',
         '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0',
         '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1',
         '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0',
         '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0',
         '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0']],

       [['0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0',
         '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0',
         '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0',
         '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0',
         '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1',
         '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0',
         '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0',
         '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0',
         '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0',
         '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0',
         '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0',
         '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0',
         '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0',
         '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0',
         '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0',
         '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0',
         '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1',
         '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0',
         '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0',
         '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0']]],
      dtype=object)
```

You may want to squeeze the result since there is an excess dimension (shape is `(2, 1, 240)`. Your desired output looks like `(2, 240)`.

Comment: I tried running that and It still displays the list identifiers. If you try with my code you might get a better idea, because maybe I'm overlooking something

Comment: @ankit That is because the lists do not all have the same length. Try `np.where(np.vectorize(len)(genes) != 240)`.

Comment: @ankit digging deeper there are unexpected characters in `newestDf`: `np.unique(newestDf.view('U1'))` gives `array(['', 'A', 'C', 'D', 'G', 'N', 'R', 'S', 'T'], dtype='<U1')`

Comment: when trying to find lines where the length wasn't 240, I ran into unexpected values therefore I assume that you are correct and that for some reason there are unexpected characters. I went even more back and found that these values are added as back as in the array df. However, I still cannot find the source because, so far, I've only found ACGT in the url data